# If you get line numbers with errors, why is it advised to use named functions for debugging purposes?

Tags: javascript

I was going through this [example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)

```
const foo = function() {
   console.log("foobar");
}
// Invoke it using the variable
foo();
```

and saw this recommendation:

> Even if your function was named, you can use the variable name to
>   invoke it. Naming it will be helpful when debugging your code. But it
>   won't affect the way we invoke it.

So I ran it with `node` but modified it to:

```js
// anonymous function
const foo = function() {
    console.log("foo");
    console.log(axe);      //added line to create error
}
foo();  // invoke function with parentheses
```

and got the error:

```sh
/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:8
    console.log(axe);
                ^

ReferenceError: axe is not defined
    at foo (/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:8:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:10:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Now with a named function `logBar()`:

```
const bar = function logBar() {
    console.log("bar");
    console.log(axe);
}
bar();
```

I don't get any extra information:

```
/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:14
    console.log(axe);
                ^

ReferenceError: axe is not defined
    at logBar (/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:14:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Documents/Practice/JavaScript/MDN/first_class_function.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Since node is telling me what line the issue arose, doesn't this eliminate the reason to use named functions for debugging purposes? Unless by debugging they mean find out what the function is used for without all the context and parsing through code if there is complicated business logic. What other debugging issues could the authors of MDN have been alluding to?

Comment: It helps if the function is anonymous and no function name can be inferred, e.g. for callback functions: `const callSomeFunction = (func) => func(); callSomeFunction(function(){ throw new Error(); })();`. A stacktrace would just label it _`<anonymous>` called by `callSomeFunction`_. In the case of `const foo = function(){` … `};`, the function name `foo` is [inferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#Inferred_function_names).

Comment: In what cases can't the function name be inferred with the exception of pre-ES2015?

Answer (score 0):

The MDN documentation may have been written before ES2015, which added function name inferences for a number of common cases.

But an anonymous function can be used without ever associating it with a name:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(axe);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So using pre-ES2015 JS as linked by user4642212 in comment to question?